# Display image as background in fullcalendar

Tags: jquery, css, image, background, fullcalendar

I have been looking for some code to use an image as a background for the events in fullcalendar ([fullcalendar jQuery](https://fullcalendar.io/)), but all I was able to find was code to add icons to said events.

I am looking to do something like this:

[image: event with image background]

UPDATE: 2016-09-23 8:15 p.m. EST:

I have been trying with:

```
eventRender: function(event, element) {
$(element).find(".fc-day").css("background","url(https://www.mozilla.org/media/img/firefox/firefox-256.e2c1fc556816.jpg) no-repeat");
$(element).find(".fc-day").css("background-size","contain");
    }
});
```

With no success so far, I'll keep looking to find what I am missing.

UPDATE: 2016-09-24 2:00 p.m. EST

Progression:

```
    dayRender: function (date, cell) {
        cell.css("background","url(https://www.mozilla.org/media/img/firefox/firefox-256.e2c1fc556816.jpg) no-repeat center");
        cell.css("background-size","contain")
    },
    eventRender: function(event, element) {
        $(element).css("opacity", "0.75");
    }
});
```

Now I just need to find a way to change the background and opacity on specific events as the event will be stored in a MySQL database as I specified already in a comment (event with no picture should not have a background nor opacity).

Comment: do you have knowledge of css?

Comment: I do, I am no expert though, I thought that the background "loading" of the event was done within the javascript/AJAX code. I'll take a look at the CSS part.

Comment: Re: updated @ 815EST with eventRender the **element** isn't the day container but rather the anchor tag. You may be able to hook with dayRender https://fullcalendar.io/docs/display/dayRender/ to do it by date?

Comment: You are right, dayRender was the way to go.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with CSS as @**madalin ivascu** mentioned

https://jsfiddle.net/j49qtcge/

```
#calendar td.fc-day {
    background: url('https://www.mozilla.org/media/img/firefox/firefox-256.e2c1fc556816.jpg') no-repeat;
    background-size: contain; // cover?
}
#calendar a.fc-event {
    opacity: 0.75;
}
```

Using views other than 'month' may need different CSS though

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer, this will surely greatly help me. I'll do further testing as I am going to get pictures inside a database linked to the calendar in MySQL. I have found the following: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_rendering/eventRender/ which will help rendering pictures according to the event. I'll keep you all posted with the code

Answer (score 0):

I'm from the future writing =)

I tried this answer:

```
 eventRender: function(event, element) { 
    element.find('.fc-event-inner').css("background","url(https://assets.pokemon.com/assets//cms2-es-es/img/play-games/mini-games/alolan-volcanic-panic/alolan-volcanic-panic-169.jpg) no-repeat right");
    element.find('.fc-event-inner').css("background-size","contain");
    element.find('.fc-event-inner').css("opacity","0.75");
  }
```