# Need to change event background and opacity in FullCalendar

Tags: php, mysql, css, image, fullcalendar

As a follow up to [Display image as background in fullcalendar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39653635/display-image-as-background-in-fullcalendar), I now have a fully working MySQL solution, but I cannot find a way to change the background if a custom column that I set in my database is not empty (picture), nor changing the same opacity according to the same condition.

In my other question, I was able to change the background in dayRender and the opacity in eventRender:

```
dayRender: function (date, cell) {
    cell.css("background","url(https://www.mozilla.org/media/img/firefox/firefox-256.e2c1fc556816.jpg) no-repeat center");
    cell.css("background-size","contain")
},
eventRender: function(event, element) {
    $(element).css("opacity", "0.75");
}
```

});

Now my **js** code looks like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var date = new Date();
    var d = date.getDate();
    var m = date.getMonth();
    var y = date.getFullYear();

    var calendar = $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        editable: true,
        header: {
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'month'
        },
        events: "/events.php",
        dayRender: function (date, cell, view) { 
             cell.css("background","url(https://www.mozilla.org/media/img/firefox/firefox-256.e2c1fc556816.jpg) no-repeat center");
             cell.css("background-size","contain")
        },
        eventRender: function(event, element) {

        }
    });
})
```

The **PHP** page to get the event data from the MySQL database is:

```
<?php
    // List of events
    $json = array();

    // Query that retrieves events
    $requete = "SELECT * FROM evenement ORDER BY id";

    // connection to the database
    try {
        $bdd = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=HIDDEN', 'HIDDEN', 'HIDDEN');
    } catch(Exception $e) {
        exit('Unable to connect to database.');
    }
    // Execute the query
    $resultat = $bdd->query($requete) or die(print_r($bdd->errorInfo()));

    // sending the encoded result to success page
    echo json_encode($resultat->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC));
?>
```

I tried to use this in dayRender to change the background with no success so far:

```
var eventoObj = $("#calendar").fullCalendar( 'clientEvents')[0];
alert(eventoObj.picture_url)
```

Can anyone help me out figuring this out?

Thank you for your time and help.

Answer (score 0):

Late but for people with same problem

Have you try to edit `fc-bg-event` class in css ?
You could set opacity to `0.1` or `0.9` for exemple and it will change opacity of event